# androidx.lifecycle or android.arch.lifecycle

Tags: android, kotlin

What is the difference between

```
android.arch.lifecycle vs androidx.lifecycle
```

Code:

```
val loading: LiveData<Boolean>
    get() = webDataSource.loading
```

When I try to auto-import, I need the arch version but it is importing the x version

I use both in the gradle file

Comment: AndroidX was announced in 2018. It is a repackaging of the former Android Support Library and Architecture Components. The `android.arch.lifecycle` artifact is no longer being maintained -- `androidx.lifecycle` is what developers should be using. "I need the arch version" -- why? "I use both in the gradle file" -- that is not a good idea. My guess is that the Jetifier is attempting to make sense of what you have requested and is trying to standardize you on using `androidx` artifacts.

Comment: Man it's you still in the android world, I started learning from your resources :) This answers my question, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"android.arch" was a way to add architecture components to projects before androidx. All-new support library development will occur in the androidx library. So the androidx package would contain new improvements and packaging structure.

Better to use the androidx components instead of "android.arch" components.